# How to use angular bundle in spring boot

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, gradle, multi-module

I have created a multi-module Gradle project for my web application and hosting it with a spring boot jar. The backend is in spring boot and the frontend is in Angular.

```
├───gradle
│   └───wrapper
├───backend
│   └───build.gradle
│   └───src
│       ├───main
│       │   ├───java
│       │   │   └───org
│       │   │       └───alpha
│       │   │           └───transaction
│       │   └───resources
│       └───test
└───frontend
    └───build.gradle
    ├───e2e
    │   └───src
    └───src
        ├───app
        ├───assets
        └───environments
```

Now to include my angular code in spring boot, I have created a jar that has the agnular bundle and injected it in spring boot.

Frontend build.gradle

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id "com.moowork.node" version "1.2.0"
}

node {
  version = '12.12.0'
  download = true
}

jar.dependsOn 'npm_run_build'

jar {
  from 'dist/frontend' into 'static'
}
```

Backend build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(':frontend'))
    // ... other dependencies
}
```

When I run the unit test in CI build it always goes and builds the angular component first before running the tests which take around a couple of more minutes.

How can I refer to the angular bundle dynamically? Is there any other way to include angular bundle in spring boot?